# How to get speed of a train without using GPS

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, proximitysensor

How can I measure approximate speed of a train  in which I am travelling without using GPS/location services?

The train can start underground or can start from ground level (where GPS is available) and then get underground in the subsequent stations.

The sensors which are present in iPhone are:

> Proximity sensor
>
> Ambient light sensor
>
> Accelerometer
>
> Magnetometer
>
> Gyroscopic sensor

and a Camera.

Can I use any of these or combinations of these to find the average speed of a train ?

I just want to know whether it is possible and if so, then please give me right direction to proceed further.

Comment: so this is a physics question, not programming

Comment: Theoretically you can integrate the accelerometer data over time to get a velocity, but this will of course only work if you start when the train is stopped. If you start measuring when the train is already moving, then the only way to determine the velocity would be to 'look outside' (gps, or film through the window and use motion tracking to determine a velocity). Special relativity tells us there aren't really any other ways – if the train is a black box and isn't accelerating, you can't get any information about your relative velocity at all.

Comment: you can always ask the conductor, they might let you to ask the driver directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to use the accelerometer alone as there is always noise that will make it inaccurate / severely wrong.

You could use the acceleration over time to keep a cumulative velocity of sorts. But this would get confused by hand movements, shakes of the train, corners, etc...

You'd need some sort of external reference to do it with any sort of accuracy.

Something like using the camera to analyse the difference between subsequent images or something.

I imagine it's possible... but very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could use all the sensors together and estimate speed. Your results might still be poor though:

1. Cumulative accelerometer, discounting any spikes in acceleration.
2. Film outside, pull two side by side frames, pull their patterns, calculated offset between patterns. You would need to test this to know what offset equates to what speed - you would have to account for distance of objects in the frames.
3. Magnetometer - birds navigate using this I think. Not sure how accurate this is in the first place, nor how easily it is affected by non-earth magnets (probably too much noise).
4. At night, you could perhaps use shifts in the stars to calculate direction and speed? During the day, use the direction of the sun, height of the sun, date and time to calculate speed.

If you took all these methods together, you might still struggle to get an accurate result, and the user-experience might be a little terrible.